# How to compare date and time after fetching from database using php?

Tags: php, database, date, time, compare

Let's say I have this piece of code running inside a loop where `$fid` will receive a value at each round:

```
     $result2 = mysql_query( "SELECT date_create FROM users WHERE id = $fid");
```

Now, date_create will be in the format  e.g

> 2012-08-16 20:13:49

My question is, how do I check if that date is before 2012-08-31, like 2012-08-10 ?

My full code, just in case one asks about it.

```
$query = "(SELECT distinct fid FROM coin WHERE uid = 59  )";
$result = mysql_query($query);
while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    $fid = $rows['fid'];
    echo 'fid || '.$fid;
    $result2 = mysql_query( "SELECT id, date_create FROM users WHERE id = $fid");
     $rows2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2);

     echo "  ||   users id : " . $rows2['id']; 

     if( $rows2['date_create'] < "2012-8-31") // How do i get something like this? 
     {

          echo "  ||   date_create : " . $rows2['date_create'] ." True"; 

     }
     else
     {
           echo "  ||   date_create : " . $rows2['date_create'] . "False"; 
     }  
    l();
}
```

Result I get so far is something like:

```
fid || 1112 || users id : 1112 || date_create : 2012-08-16 20:13:49 false <--
fid || 1113 || users id : 1113 || date_create : 2012-08-16 20:14:11 false <--
fid || 1115 || users id : 1115 || date_create : 2012-08-16 20:14:21 false <--
fid || 1117 || users id : 1117 || date_create : 2012-08-16 20:14:38 false <--
fid || 1118 || users id : 1118 || date_create : 2012-08-16 20:15:03 false <--
fid || 1119 || users id : 1119 || date_create : 2012-08-16 20:15:10 false <--
```

n.b would appreciate if also you could provide a way to check time. This would be extra :D

Comment: use mysqli module, mysql depricated

Comment: MySQL offers quite a rich set of Date functions, http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by converting the date/time string and compare it using [strtotime()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php). Using that method, you can also adapt it to compare for seconds as well:

```
//this effectively checks to see that the time is greater than '2012-08-16 20:13:49'
//the total calculated time on the RHS of the >= operator is effectively '2012-08-16 20:13:49'
//hence, this will echo 'YES'

//this is of the form: hours, minutes, seconds
$time_difference = (44 * 60 * 60) + (13 * 60) + 49;

if (strtotime('2012-08-16 20:13:49') >= strtotime('2012-08-15') + $time_difference)
{
  echo 'YEAH';
}
else
{
  echo 'NO';
}
```

UPDATE:

From the PHP documentation on [strtotime()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php):

> The valid range of a timestamp is typically from Fri, 13 Dec 1901
>   20:45:54 UTC to Tue, 19 Jan 2038 03:14:07 UTC. (These are the dates
>   that correspond to the minimum and maximum values for a 32-bit signed
>   integer.) Additionally, not all platforms support negative timestamps,
>   therefore your date range may be limited to no earlier than the Unix
>   epoch. This means that e.g. dates prior to Jan 1, 1970 will not work
>   on Windows, some Linux distributions, and a few other operating
>   systems. PHP 5.1.0 and newer versions overcome this limitation though.
>
> For 64-bit versions of PHP, the valid range of a timestamp is
>   effectively infinite, as 64 bits can represent approximately 293
>   billion years in either direction.

Comment: +1 and correct answer and besides, it looks nice . How confident are you about it?

Comment: Very. I updated my answer to better clarify it for you. In summary, the compared date ('2012-08-15') is _exactly_ **(44 * 60 * 60) + (13 * 60) + 49;** seconds from '2012-08-16 20:13:49'.

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this:

```
$result = mysql_query($query);
$chk = strtotime("2012-08-31");
while( $rows = mysql_fetch_array($result) ) {
    $fid = $rows['fid'];
    echo 'fid || '.$fid;
    $result2 = mysql_query( "SELECT id, date_create FROM users WHERE id = $fid");
     $rows2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2);
     echo "  ||   users id : " . $rows2['id']; 
     if( $chk - strtotime($rows2['date_create']) > 0) {
          echo "  ||   date_create : " . $rows2['date_create'] ." True"; 
     }
     else {
           echo "  ||   date_create : " . $rows2['date_create'] . "False"; 
     }
    l();
}
```

Documentation on php.net for [`strtotime()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php).

Comment: One of the answers did as u suggested, but, he added 
strtotime('2012-08-10') + 24 * 60 * 60

Answer (score 1):

Better is to use the following query:

```
SELECT id, date_create,unix_timestamp(date_create) as time_stamp FROM users WHERE id = $fid"
```

and compare  time_stamp variable which is int

Comment: I would prefer to fetch date as it's and compare it elsewhere. Thanks for the effort.